# Sentinel 1 relative orbit

Tags: sentinel-1

Does somebody know where you can find the relative orbit number of a Sentinel 1 image? I know it should be somewhere in the metadata (the xml-file), but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5):

You actually can find the relative orbit number of sentinel-1 image from the filename by deriving absolute orbit number provided in the name.

[The formula are:](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/sentinel-1-relative-orbit-from-filename/7042/2)

- Sentinel-1A Relative Orbit Number = mod (Absolute Orbit Number orbit - 73, 175) + 1
- Sentinel-1B Relative Orbit Number = mod (Absolute Orbit Number orbit - 27, 175) + 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. You need to parse the `manifest.xml` file.

Here's how to do it in Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(manifest_path)
ns = {'safe': 'http://www.esa.int/safe/sentinel-1.0'}
start_relative_orbit_number = tree.find('.//safe:relativeOrbitNumber[@type="start"]', ns).text
end_relative_orbit_number = tree.find('.//safe:relativeOrbitNumber[@type="stop"]', ns).text
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your information right here....
https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/portal/doc/call/fp7/fp7-space-2012-1/31660-s1-rs-mda-52-7441_v2_2_productspecification_en.pdf

More information there if you have not seen this :

https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-1-sar/revisit-and-coverage